# Magento's Config File

Tags: magento

How can we define multiple classes for Helpers, Block in magento and how to access it i tried below code

```
   <helpers>
        <basic>
            <class>Trimantra_Basic_Helper</class>
        </basic>   
        <basic_product>
            <class>Trimantra_Basic_Helper_Product</class>
        </basic_product>
    </helpers>
```

but this give me a warning

```
include(Trimantra\Basic\Helper\Product\Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I don't wont to have

> Trimantra_Basic_Helper_Product_Data

i need

> Trimantra_Basic_Helper_Product

Can any one please guide me ...

And one more help .. Does any one know any good source in order to learn thing related to various XML files in Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define multiple classes. Just make you config look like this:

```
<helpers>
    <basic>
        <class>Trimantra_Basic_Helper</class>
    </basic>   
</helpers>
```

Calling `Mage::helper('basic')` will create an instance of `Trimantra_Basic_Helper_Data`.
If you want an instance of `Trimantra_Basic_Helper_Product` just call

```
Mage::helper('basic/product')
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. Was looking for the same

Comment: Hello Marius, If possible, can you share tip and tricks for various XML Files in Magento.

Comment: @Rakesh. You should be more specific. There are a lot of tips and tricks. And also I don't know what you consider tip/trick. Ask specific questions and I'll answer if I know the answer. Also consider taking a look or posting questions here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/. You might have more luck.

Comment: Thanks you. henceforth I will be more specific while asking question/suggestion.